# How do I have different envirenment variable values in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is how I run `rails console` command:

```
COMPANY=b2b RAILS_ENV=development DEPLOY_ENV=localhost rails console
```

Instead I want to run only `rails console` command by setting these variables internally. How do I do that?

I saw some answers and made the `config/company.yml` file:

```
development:
  COMPANY: b2b
  DEPLOY_ENV: localhost

production:
  COMPANY: b2c
  DEPLOY_ENV: xyz.com
```

And I wrote the following `config/initializers/company.rb` file:

```
COMPANY_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/company.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

How do I access these variables in some helper/controller? I didn't understand how to do that? **How do I set these ENV variables after running only `rails console` or `rails server` without passing the extra environment variable shown above?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't set environment variables in yaml file this difference things. Use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem for manage environment variables.

Read first [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

But have dirty hack. You can create ENV variable when rails loaded

add this code to `before_configuration` in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'company.yml') # Find yml file
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|       # Open file
    ENV[key.to_s] = value                                   # Set value to ENV
  end if File.exists?(env_file)                             # If file exists
end
```

And now you can access to env variables from yml file anywhere in app.

<strike>I do not test this but i think this work.</strike> 
This work.

[Some info](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

Comment: Where should I add this code? I didn't find `before_configuration` in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Read about [initialization-events](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events).

Answer (score 1):

You can create these settings variables in the `config/initializers/application.rb` file:

```
company_settings_path = Rails.root.join('config', 'company.yml')

COMPANY_CONFIG = { development: { company: :default, deploy_env: :none_yet } }
COMPANY_CONFIG = YAML::load(File.open(company_settings_path)) if File.exists?(company_settings_path)
COMPANY_CONFIG = COMPANY_CONFIG.with_indifferent_access
```

And then access them like this:

```
# controller
def show
  if COMPANY_CONFIG[:company] == 'b2c'
    # your logic
  else
    # other logic
  end
end
```

You can acces the constant `COMPANY_CONFIG` everywhere in your app (models, controllers, views, helpers) the same way I used below.